# Understanding the definition of globally generated quasi-coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I'm having trouble understanding the definition of globally generated quasi-coherent sheaves that is given in my lecture notes:

> Let $X$ be a scheme, M a quasi-coherent sheaf, then M is globally generated if it is generated by global sections, i.e. if there exist sections $s_i\in M(X),\,i\in I$ with $I$ a set, such that the map $\bigoplus_{i\in I}O_X\to M,\,e_i\mapsto s_i$ is surjective.

In particular, I don't understand the following: How is the direct sum of sheaves of rings defined and why does it even exist? What are the $e_i$? The stacks project seems to be using the notation $\bigoplus_{i\in I}O_X$ as well but I haven't found a definition so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct sum is always defined by its universal property:  $\bigoplus_i A_i$ is the universal recipient of a family of maps, one from each $A_i$, in the appropriate category.  In this case the category in question is the category of (sheaves of) $\mathcal O_X$-modules.  (Not rings--the same universal property in a category of rings defines the tensor product.)

Of course this doesn't answer the question of whether the direct sum exists; we still need to construct it.  This can be done as follows.  First, the direct sum of a family of *presheaves* is the direct sum on sections; i.e. $(\bigoplus_i \mathcal F_i)(U) = \bigoplus_i (\mathcal F_i(U))$ for each open set $U$.  The direct sum of a family of *sheaves* is the sheafification of the direct sum of the underlying presheaves.

This construction is justified by a general fact from category theory:  left adjoints commute with colimits.  The direct sum is defined as a colimit, and sheafification is left-adjoint to the inclusion functor $\mathrm{Sh} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{PSh}$, so "sheaf-direct-sum of sheafifications equals sheafification of presheaf-direct-sum".

Note also that a *finite* direct sum in an abelian category agrees with the direct product, which is a limit.  In this case the dual statement (right adjoints commute with limits) implies that the direct product of presheaves is already a sheaf:  "presheaf-direct-product of underlying presheaves equals underlying presheaf of sheaf-direct-product".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, do you also know what the $e_i\in\bigoplus_{i\in I}O_X$ mean?

Comment: I assume they're the standard basis vectors $(1, 0, \dots, 0)$ etc.

Comment: To supplement Ravi's answer to your comment, note that by his description one has that 

$$\mathscr{H}om\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^m \mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F}\right)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^m\mathscr{H}om(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$$

and $\mathscr{H}om(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$ is just $\mathcal{F}(X)$. Thus, one sees that a map from $\displaystyle \bigoplus_{i=1}^m\mathcal{O}_X$ is just the selection of $m$ global sections of $\mathcal{F}$. The notation $e_i\mapsto s_i$ means that these selected global sections are the $s_i$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks, I just noticed something: Why is $Hom(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{F})$ the same thing as $F(X)$?

Comment: @test123 There is clearly a map $Hom(\mathcal{O}_X,F)\to \mathcal{O}_X$ given by sending $f$ to $f(1)$ where $1\in\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is the unit element. This is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$-modules. The injectivity is clear since for all open subsets $U$ of $X$ the $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{F}(U)$ is determined by where it sends $1$, but this is just the restriction of $f(1)$ to $U$. It's surjective since if $s$ is in $\mathcal{F}(X)$ then the map which for every open $U$ sends $a$ to $a(s\mid_U)$ is a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{F}$ and it's clear that on global secitons $1\mapsto s$.

Comment: Also, @test123 or whover else is reading this, the $\mathscr{H}om$ above should have been $\text{Hom}$--it's the normal 'Hom' not the 'sheaf Hom'. The sheaf Hom is just $\mathcal{F}$.